# Winforms app not compiling in Release mode using Bunifu framework

Tags: bunifu

I've been working on a Winform App that uses Bunifu framework for a month and I just tried to compile in release mode for the first time.

I now get errors everywhere in the winform designer:

> The type or namespace name 'Bunifu' cannot be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?).

However I use other frameworks and no error on their side.

I find this strange because when I go back and compile in debug mode back, the errors disappear.

I am using VS code 2019.

Comment: This question has been asked zillions of times before on Stack Overflow. Please use the search feature before asking. If you've already tried all of the things suggested in the existing answers, then please [edit] your question to explain all of the things you've tried so far, and why your question is different.